upload file from browser using https for progress update
Axios seems to work quite fine for file uploads, but, since it's a Front end applications, I wanted to avoid using a third party lib for a simple file upload task.
My requirements are to be able to upload a file and get update on progress, file potentially 1-3GB in size.
Note, I can't use FormData because, I eventually want to use S3 presigned urls which use PUT and expect raw binary.
Other than using axios, I came across 2 options:

Fetch
Https module

While uploading with fetch seems to be simple, there doesn't seem to be a way to get progress update.
And the hurdle I came with https is that it seems to need a Readstream, and in browser I can't use the fs module. So, just seeing the interfaces, I did a hacky bit of code like this(taking a similar example, but one that uses form data):
import https from 'https';

// file = event.target.files[0]

export async function uploadFile(
  url: string,
  file: File,
  onProgress: () => void = noOp,
  method = REQ.PUT,
) {
  
 let progressDataLength = 0;
  let data = "";
  
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = https.request(
      {
        hostname: url,
        method: method,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": file.type,
          "Content-Length": file.size,
        },
      },
      function (res) {
        res.on("data", (chunk) => {
          progressDataLength += chunk.size;
          data += chunk;
          onProgress();
          console.log("Total received: ", `${chunk.size}/${file.size}`);
        });
        res.on("end", () => {
          resolve("Mydata: " + data);
        });
      },
    );  
       
     // MY HACKY CODE BIT
     const startConversionTime = new Date().getTime();
     Readable.from(Buffer.from(await file.arrayBuffer())).pipe(req);
     console.log(
       "Total conversion time taken: ",
       new Date().getTime() - startConversionTime,
    );  

    req.end();
  });
}

While this particular code produced the error below, I'm not sure if this is even legit at all? ( Is the conversion done right? and, I can't really find examples of File being converted to readable stream )

TypeError: The "listener" argument must be of type Function. Received type object

What are my options of implementing this function and how can it be done?
